# Gradle повисает при сборке проекта

Tags: android, linux, debian, gradle, elementary-os

При первой сборке проекта в Android Studio Gradle повисает вот на этом:
[image: Gradle: Executing Task]

Пробовал ждать несколько часов - не помогает.
Подключение к Интернет активно.
Пробовал на Ubuntu GNOME 15.04, Elementary OS Freya, Debian Jessie. Везде такая же проблема.

До этого такого не было. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: вручную команды нормально выполняются?

Comment: Несколько раз наблюдал такое. Попробуйте поменять gradle (чтобы использовал консольный gradle) или наоборот перейти на gradle-wrapper. Возможна еще версия с доступом к репозиторию maven/gradle

Answer (score 1):

Решить проблему помогает установка  следующих библиотек:

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g:i386 libc6-i386 lib32stdc++6 lib32gcc1 lib32ncurses5
```

Так же при поиске ответа наткнулся на полезную ссылку, может пригодится кому:
[Mobile Dev Install: Android on Linux](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Mobile-Dev-Install:-Android-on-Linux)

Всем спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте настроит `Gradle` работать автономно

Настройки:

[image: Оффлайн Gradle]